# Android SDK manager does not launch

Tags: android, eclipse, windows

I am not being able to start sdk `manager.exe`. i think i am very close to the solution. I have given the right path of android sdk from `Windows->preferences`. I get the following error

> Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe  -jar lib\archquery.jar

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I'd guess your environment variables need to be fixed, specifically JAVA_HOME.

In Windows 7: Start > type "environment variables" > Edit environment variables for your account.
Find JAVA_HOME in the 'System variables' list and make sure it's correct
(e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60); if it's correct, try with quotation marks (e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60").